# How to 'start and forget' Visual Studio Code from cmd?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, command-line

I would like to start VSC from a Windows command line (I use cmder) without feedback info from VSC which polluted my cmd window.

I open VSC from a Windows command with
`code .`
VSC is opened correctly but display some execution information in cmd window, like:

```
[main 2023-09-08T09:00:00.249Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled by user preference
[main 2023-09-08T09:00:02.909Z] Starting extension host with pid 27716 (fork() took 15 ms).
```

I can use the cmd window but it is polluted by vsc execution info...
How to start VSC from a command line and don't get information from execution of VSC ?

As a workaround, is there a way to launch code with "start" and redirecting standard output into a black hole ? It tried without success

```
start "" "C:\App\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" . 1>nul
```

Comment: This does not happen on my systems. I guess it depends on your installed tools

Comment: you mean my vsc version ?

Comment: VSC and other tools. Try this on newly installed Windows system. Install VSC and try again

Comment: weird. does this happen if you uninstall and then reinstall? What version of VS Code do you have installed?

Comment: Here is my VSC version used. As it is deployed by my company, I cannot uninstall and reinstall it

Version: 1.73.1 (system setup)   
Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b   
Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No

Answer (score 0):

Error may occur, try using cmd in administrator or the user logged in to windows is the administrator user and not any other, if this doesnt work try changing permission directly of VSC instead of changing from cmd.

Comment: same behavior when running from a cmd with admin rights.
I also tried to set the full rights to all users on VSC installation folder without success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more issue with 1.87.0